# select record from database and show the value on corresponding row value

Tags: c#, winforms

i got stack with im doing, i have a query that select the minimum value of my quantity, the code running fine for first query B value has a result which is correct from the record, my problem is the second OleQuery the debugging stop in OledDBDatareader and jump into another event. can someone figure our what is the problem?

```
                MyConN.Open();
                OleDbCommand OlCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select min(Cqty) from stocks", MyConN);
                OleDbDataReader OdR = OlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (OdR.Read())
                {
                    string B = OdR[0].ToString();                       
                    if (B == "")
                    {}
                    else
                    {
                        string ItemDisc;
                        string OleQuery = "select *from stocks where Cqty='" + B + "'";
                        OleDbCommand OlCmdQuery =new OleDbCommand(OleQuery, MyConN);
                        OleDbDataReader DrQuery = OlCmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
                        while(DrQuery.Read())
                        {
                            ItemDisc = (DrQuery["ItemDesc"].ToString());
                        }
                        DrQuery.Close();

                        DialogResult Result1 = MessageBox.Show("The System detects " + ItemDisc + " product with less than 10 quantity remaining " + Environment.NewLine + " Please check with the suppliers and request orders", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        if (Result1==DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                           //some message here
                        }
                    }
                    MyConN.Close();}
```

Edit: After checking the record in my database and found out that the value is numeric, in my second query i only remove the single quote and the query response as i want.

Comment: How does the event, where your program is jumping to, looks like?

Comment: the next event is command button, nothing happen on the process i want, no message show instead its show the form

Comment: and why don't you make it on a sigle select instead of a nested subselect?

    select * from stocks where Cqty = (Select min(Cqty) from stocks)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you use simultaneously two active dataReaders and this may cause an Exception. Perhaps this is why debugging it goes to another event, because an unhandled exception occurs and continues executing without giving any info (??)

Try adding this code to your database connection string and let me know if it works properly now.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

Another option is get first reader into a dataset, close the datareader and iterate the dataset in the second bucle.

Hope it helps!

Comment: david, added  + "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" on the end of my connection string, nothing happen.